# Php simple insert is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to insert some values in to mysql database via php code. It is straight forward, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$mjesto = $_POST['mjesto'];
$ptt = $_POST['ptt'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$a=1;

$conn = new mysqli('server', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$sql = "insert into imtecEvents values
   ('".$a."', '".$first."', '".$last."', '".$address."', '".$mjesto."', '".$ptt."', '".$email."', '".$phone."', '".$a."' )";

$conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: 1. do you get any error? 2. do you understand, that this is an invitation to SQL-injection?

Comment: your query is incorrect: you must specify which coloumns you need to fill, like: "insert into TABLENAME (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (field1value,field2value,field3value")" Also, as JimiDini said, your code is vulnerable to sql injections, you should prepare the query first and check the values you get BEFORE doing the query.

Comment: insert into imtecEvents (column1,etc.....) values ('value1',etc.....)

Comment: @briosheje and roullie This isn't necessary. I would suggest to put a `or die(mysqli_error());` after the query.

Comment: It is just for education purposes, and I didn't get any error. Also, I am populating every column in the table, so it is not necessary to specify them explicitly.

Comment: why not just use prepared statements

Comment: @GuyT: seriously? It currently doesn't work to me without setting the coloumns.. Maybe something relative to the sql version?

Comment: Are you entering correct no. of values? $a is added twice.

Comment: I am, as I said, it is just for educational purposes.

Comment: @briosheje check out my fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f47e6/1

Comment: @GuyT: Thanks, that's intersting :P Still wondering why it doesn't work in my network though.

Comment: @briosheje yup. column names are optional. but you have to maintain the order then.

Comment: Couldn't it be that you have a duplicate entry issue. You have your id as a fixed number and in a usual layout the id needs to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

at least you should use [MYSQLI PREPARE](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to avoid mysql injection

in your code

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

try to add this code **exit($conn->error())**, to determine if the error is with your sql, thus;

```
$conn->query($sql) or exit($conn->error());
```

if not, issue a var_dump with all the data that you inserted to trace

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all of the `$_POST` array values are set? try to print that array `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to make sure if the values are set. Second, try to check if the order/number of the values you are inserting is the same of that on the DB.

Comment: I am sure, because I am sending the values to my mail, and the order is good too.